# Git rebase noise

Tags: git, version-control, rebase, noise

that is maybe a silly question (for sure) but for everything that I have read / found none matches what I want to do... and that is a GIT basic situation.

To make my situation more simple I have two branches :
  - master (main branch)
  - feature (created from master)

I work on my feature branch, during this time other people make changes to master, changes that I would like to retrieve on my feature branch.
I kown I have to use `git rebase` beacause I just want to keep my feature branch up to date.
The problem is that when I rebase `git checkout feature && git reabse master` the retrieved commits are in the commit list to be pushed.

To summarize I would like that when I do my rebase and I push, there is only my commits performed on feature and only those, not those from the rebase. I would like my rebase be silent, without making noise to my feature branch.

If needed I can show my .gitconfig file.
FYI I work on PhpStorm with GIT interface, but my problem is the same with command line

Thank you,
Matthéo Geoffray.

Comment: I wouldn't do this at all. You should work on your `feature` branch and, once the feature has been completed merge it back into `master`. In rebasing it every time, your are changing your development history, which is exactly what git tracks.

Comment: @daniel Maybe a wrong config on my side because after `git pull --rebase origin master && git log origin/master..HEAD` I can see the master commits.

Comment: @HBHB I am totally agree with you on this point but the workflow that I use in my agency is a little more complex than my example. So in some case we have to do this, retrieve updates from our master branch.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer the question myself !

PhpStorm misled me, as I said it shows me the list of all the commits from master when I want to push on my feature branch. I try to push them anyway, that notice me that I have pushed XXX commits (same as master commits) but on Gitlab when I want to do my merge request between `feature` and `master` only my additional commits to `feature` where purposed.

Visually in PhpStorm and Gitlab it is not the best solution but at least the result is that what I want.

Maybe I am wrong so if anyone have a better solution / answer I am open to others.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve updates from master, one option could be that you merge latest master to your feature branch before pushing. One drawback of git merge is it pollutes the history with merge commits.

Git rebase is ideal for feature branches that are not yet pushed to remote. 
When you're working alone on a project, rewriting history isn't a big deal. However, as soon as you start working in a collaborative environment, it can become very dangerous. If you rewrite commits that other developers are using (e.g., commits on the master branch), it will look as if those commits vanished the next time they try to pull in your work. This results in a confusing scenario that's difficult to recover from.

So git merge best fits for branches that are pushed to remote and git rebase is good for local branches so that the history remains clean.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. In my case we have a new branch for each issue, new feature, each created from master. In most cases branches are not yet pushed but i see the difference and the possible issue with your explanation. I'll try next time the case show up ! Thanks.